# Correct Syntax for With Sheets ("") .Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that works perfectly fine in getting the unique values in column D and pasting them into the worksheet "Summary-Champion Specific". I'm now having some syntax problems. Instead of creating the Worksheet "Summary-Champion Specific", i want to just select it (so it's already created).

```
 Dim dict As Object, LastRow As Long, c
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    With Sheets("Raw Data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each c In .Range("D8:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dict(c.Text) = 0
        Next
    End With
    Champ = dict.keys

    With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
      .Name = "c"
      .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
      .Range(Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1), Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
    End With
```

Basically i want to change the second section above to the code below.

```
With Sheets("c")
  .Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
  .Range(Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1), Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
End With
```

When i try to run this however, it fails with error 1004. Have i messed up the syntax somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refer to the Cells with a point. Like this:

```
With Sheets("Summary-Champion Specific")
  .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
  .Range(.Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1), .Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
End With
```

Thus, you would refer to the correct WorkSheet. The `.Cells` is a property of the worksheet -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel

Answer (score 2):

As Vityata pointed out, `Cells` is different to `Worksheet.Cells`, as `Cells` refers to the ActiveSheet.

But the `Sheets` command will also refer to the ActiveWorkbook, which might not be the one you want. Furthermore, the `Sheets("SheetName")` syntax is implicitly calling the `_Default` member of `Sheets` and returning an `Object` reference, so the calls within the `With` block are all late-bound, and will be slow as a result, and you won't get any Intellisense.

It's better to use the (meaningful) codename of the sheet within your workbook:

```
With SummaryChampionSpecific 'Where SummaryChampionSpecific is the CodeName of Sheets("Summary-Champion Specific")
  .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
  .Range(.Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1), .Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
End With
```

or set a `Worksheet` variable, and then use that in a `With` block:

```
Dim mySheet as Worksheet
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbooks.Worksheets("Summary-Champion Specific")
With mySheet
  .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
  .Range(.Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1), .Cells(8 + UBound(Champ), 1)).Resize(dict.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
End With
```

That code will run faster and be easier to maintain.